# Can I decrypt and encrypt again my OS drive and will I loose data in this process?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, disk-encryption, decryption

I need to decrypt my OS drive (turn off bitlocker) to be able to install Ubuntu alongside Win10, and I would like to encrypt again Windows side after the installation for safety issues. Can I loose data in the decryption process? ?

Comment: The decryption and encryption processes do not usually lose data. But you should always have backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes!

If the process is interrupted, you'll have to [recover the volume to another one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/repair-bde). It's less than ideal.

The solution is to have backups. Backups are a necessity, not an option, and you don't make them only before risky operations - you should make sure they update automatically and frequently. You can lose data due to hardware failures, viruses, software errors, human errors, fires, cataclysms etc. Disk decryption is just one more reason to this list.